# Bubblesort with C

Tags: c, unix, bubble-sort

I have a really simple (or at least it should be) assignment in which I have to run bubblesort on a large array of random numbers and see its performance time. I then have to do the same thing except split up the array in half and sort one half in one thread and another in the other thread and see if it is any faster that way.

I've never worked with C before so I am completely clueless when it comes to pointers, having only worked with Java. Here is my code so far as I am just trying to get the bubblesort to work.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int main() {
  int *array[50000];
  for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    array[i] = 1;
  }
  bubbleSort(array, 50000);
}

void bubbleSort(int *numbers[], int *array_size) {
  int i, j, temp;
  for(i = (array_size - 1); i > 0; i--) {
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
  if(numbers[j-1] > numbers[j]) {
    temp = numbers[j-1];
    numbers[j-1] = numbers[j];
    numbers[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf(numbers[i]);
  }
}
```

All I'm trying to do here is sort the array and then print out the first ten numbers just so I know it's working. I'm getting all kinds of pointer errors.

```
"bubbleSort.c", line 11: warning: improper pointer/integer combination: op "="
"bubbleSort.c", line 13: warning: implicit function declaration: bubbleSort
"bubbleSort.c", line 16: identifier redeclared: bubbleSort
        current : function(pointer to pointer to int, pointer to int) returning void
        previous: function() returning int : "bubbleSort.c", line 13
"bubbleSort.c", line 18: warning: improper pointer/integer combination: op "="
"bubbleSort.c", line 21: warning: improper pointer/integer combination: op "="
"bubbleSort.c", line 23: warning: improper pointer/integer combination: op "="
"bubbleSort.c", line 28: warning: argument #1 is incompatible with prototype:
        prototype: pointer to const char : "/usr/include/iso/stdio_iso.h", line 206
        argument : pointer to int
cc: acomp failed for bubbleSort.c
```

Comment: `array[i] = 1;` I know, determined by fair die roll and all, but that's not what's meant with "array of random numbers" to test the performance.

Comment: oops, I had changed this because I was getting an error from it and forgot to change it back before posting. Instead of one I had rand() there, but it didn't like that. Let me change it back now and see what the error was.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
int *array[50000];
```

declares a 50,000-element array of pointers to `int`, which is probably not what you want. Remove the `*`.

In the `bubbleSort()` prototype you're also having spurious asterisks that should be removed.

Please note that the asterisk *means* something in C, you're not supposed to just randomly decorate your code with them wherever you feel like. If you're unsure *what* it means and *when*, you should have access to some tutorial information if this is for a class. Start reading.

Comment: I originally had it all done without the pointers. I'd like to avoid them if possible. Unfortunately, this isn't an introductory course and we are kind of getting thrown into the fire and expected to know C.

When I remove the asterisk's from both the array and the params for the bubbleSort method, here is the error I get that led me to believe I needed asterisks.

    `code`"bubbleSort.c", line 16: identifier redeclared: bubbleSort
            current : function(pointer to int, int) returning void
            previous: function() returning int :     "bubbleSort.c",     line 13 `code`

Answer (score 1):

**line 11:** You should not have declared `int *array[]` but `int array[]` instead
**line 13:** Prototype your function or declare it above your main
**line 16:** You declared `int *array_size` but in the main you give it an `int`
**line 18, 21 and 23:** Same as **11**.
**line 28: Never** use printf with a variable format string ! `printf("%i, ", numbers[i]);` is the way.

You should really review C coding basics

Comment: Thank you. Seems like just a few things are different than languages that I am used to, I have a little work to do. Thanks again.